# nested (IF-AND-IF-ISERROR) statement (Excel)

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested

I am trying to overcomplicate a formula, where I basically check if cell 1 = 70 and cell 2 <> 70, then search another cell for a specific text ("OF" in my case). If the text exists, return "YES", otherwise keep everything as it is.

This is what I have so far

```
=IF(YD2=70 AND(YE2<>70, IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*OF*",YA2))), "YES", YD2)YD2))
```

Help? :)

Comment: Anyone? Is it even possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do it:

`=IF(AND(YD2=70,YE2<>70),IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*OF*",YA2))),"YES",YD2),YD2)`

You were just missing the `,` before the last `YD2` and the `AND` I reworked.